# java project in eclipse luna ant build fails but works in eclipse neon

Tags: java, eclipse

I need to be able to run the same project using different eclipse projects.  We need to upgrade the project from jdk1.6 to jdk1.8. So I have EclipseLuna for the jdk1.6 version and EclipseNeon for the 1.8 version.

I have the 1.8 version building and running. But when I try to build the 1.6 version in Luna I get this error:

> do-project-taskproxy:
>         [ant] Ant: Can't set output to ${DIR_LOC_BUILD_TDD}/logs/20181435/Secbuild.xml-clean-compile.stdout

The property file has the DIR_LOC_BUILD_TDD defined in the same way for both workspaces.

There are additional errors after this that are looking for an xml file that is also in the correct path.
The error is as follows:

> BUILD FAILED C:\Development\\build.xml:327: The following
>   error occurred while executing this line:
>   C:\Development\\build.xml:306:  The following error occurred
>   while executing this line: C:\Development\\build.xml:242:
>   The following error occurred while executing this line:
>   C:\Development\\build.xml:259: The following error occurred
>   while executing this line:
>   C:\Development\\build-core.xml:39: Cannot find
>   C:\Development\\${cm.hm}\cm-ant-library.xml imported from
>   C:\Development\\build-core.xml

I removed the project name for security..

I have tried using the same workspace and copying the workspace to a different directory for each Eclipse version but I get the same error.
The only difference is the Eclipse version.

Can anyone tell me why the Luna version is giving this error and Neon builds successfully?

**UPDATE**
It seems to the error is occurring to 'clean-compile' phase..which doesn't make sense to me.  There is nothing to clean because I have not successfully compiled yet.
Here is the error:

> clean-compile: subproject-parallel-taskproxy:
>        [echo] clean-compile  - Security 
>        [echo] clean-compile  - Core - framework. do-project-taskproxy: do-project-taskproxy:
>         [ant] Ant: Can't set output to ${DIR_LOC_BUILD_TDD}/logs/20181544/Secbuild.xml-clean-compile.stdout
>
> BUILD FAILED C:\Dev\AUTOMATION\build.xml:327: The
>   following error occurred while executing this line:

**UPDATE**
There is a problem with sharing of files.  I tried deleting the workspace for the Luna project and I could not unless I closed the Neon Eclipse.
I will recreate the workspace from source control and see if that allows for compiling..

**UPDATE**
Still getting the same error.:(

**UPDATE**
Tried running Luna has an Admin and got the same error.
I added another Maven project and could successfully build it.
I added another Ant project to see if I could build it. The options on the *Targets* tab do not list the compile options.
In the Neon Eclipse it looks like this:
[image]

Same project in different workspace folder using Luna running as Admin looks like this:
[image]

The options are imported from the xml that is giving the error...*(${cm.hm}cm-ant-library.xml*
This xml file is in the project that I need to compile.  How can I import this?

Comment: Please use the current version of Eclipse (Oxygen.3a) to avoid running into already fixed bugs and specify the JDK that you want to use to run the Ant build in the Ant _External Tools Configurations_ in the _JRE_ tab (you first have to specify the JDKs you want use in _Window > Preferences: Java > Installed JREs_).

Comment: The newer version of Eclipse (Neon) is not giving me a problem.  It is the older version that I need to run using JDK1.6 (Luna).  In the build configuration - JRE tab, I selected 'Separate JRE' and am using jdk1.6.

Comment: Make also sure the _Base Directory_ (in the _Main_ tab) is the same for both (if empty, the directory of the build file is used). Can you tell us what exactly happens in line 39 of `C:\Development\\build-core.xml`? It looks like `${DIR_LOC_BUILD_TDD}` and `${cm.hm}` have not been resolved (maybe because of a properties file with a relative path and a wrong base directory).

Comment: My _Base Directory_ was blank.  So, I tried using the _workspace_ button to specify and that did not work.  I also tried the _File System' option and that also did not work.  I get the same error.  In the properties file, `cm.hm` is set to `../<Project Name>`. `DIR_LOC_BUILD_TDD' is set to `/opt/...BUILD/...`

Comment: What do you mean...CLI?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably it is due to different ANT versions used inside these eclipse versions. To fix this, you can try creating different workspace for each eclipse and then try building it. According to my understanding you are trying to use same workspace for both eclipse.

Comment: They are now separate workspaces and I am still getting the same error.

Comment: try starting eclipse luna as administrator.

Comment: Ran eclipse luna as Admin.  Still the same error.  (This is really frustrating!)  I can successfully built a Maven project.  I will see if I can find another Ant project to build and see if it is the project of the type of build.